# How to Preview extensionless files in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, registry

I want to use the Windows 10 Preview Pane to view the text of extensionless files (such as Dockerfile, Jenkinsfile, README, etc)

Is there a registry key in the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes` tree that Windows uses to designate a files with no extension? I've tried using the full name of the file, `[]`, and `.` as the key, to no avail.

Here's an example of it working on a `.dockerignore` file. The preview pane shows the file's contents.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.dockerignore]
"Content Type"="text/plain"
"PerceivedType"="text"
```

Or is this simply not possible/supported in Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.\ShellEx]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.\ShellEx\{8895b1c6-b41f-4c1c-a562-0d564250836f}]
@="{1531d583-8375-4d3f-b5fb-d23bbd169f22}"
```

Here

- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.` means *a file with no extension*;
- `{8895b1c6-b41f-4c1c-a562-0d564250836f}` means the [*preview handler*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23633246/3439404);
- `{1531d583-8375-4d3f-b5fb-d23bbd169f22}` means *Windows TXT Previewer*, see also output from `reg query "HKCR\CLSID\{1531d583-8375-4d3f-b5fb-d23bbd169f22}"`

**Result check**:

```
reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\." /S
```

> ```
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.\ShellEx
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.\ShellEx\{8895b1c6-b41f-4c1c-a562-0d564250836f}
>     (Default)    REG_SZ    {1531d583-8375-4d3f-b5fb-d23bbd169f22}
> ```

**Create an example**:

```
echo a plain text file with no extension>D:\test\NoExtesionFiles\NoExtensionTxt
```

**Result view**:

[image]

Comment: For some reason that is not working on the machine I wanted it to, but my laptop it does. The ShellEx and Preview handler GUIDs were the key to this, PerceivedType just isn't enough :). Also the 'Unknown' key is for extensions that are not mapped to anything else, so that's nice to know as well!

Answer (score 0):

To allow reading file content for files with `.ext` extensions in the windows 10 explorer preview pane, set

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ext
        PerceivedType     REG_SZ     Text
```

Usually the `.ext` key already exists, and it is simply a matter of adding the PerceivedType string value and setting it to `Text`. In my case, the `.`  key with no extension didn't exist, so I created it (New key, `.`) and then added `PerceivedType' as above.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell script:

```
$EXTENSION = "" # empty string for Dockerfile, could be 'yaml' or 'json'
[microsoft.win32.registry]::SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\."+"$EXTENSION", "PerceivedType", "text")
```